# Распознавание цвета по ключевому слову вместо формата (r, g, b)

Tags: python, python-3.x, color, pygame

Я пишу Pong в PyGame и хотел бы использовать цвета по ключевым значениям, но при их использовании интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку. Вот конкретный кусок кода:

```
def main():
    gameOver = False
    myPaddle = Paddle(10, 10, 5, 20, white)
```

Ошибка:

> Exception has occurred: NameError
>
> > name 'white' is not defined

Подскажите, возможно есть какой нибудь модуль, который позволит решить проблему, или возможно я что-то не так делаю. Понимаю, что заведомое определение white как (255, 255, 255) поможет, но не считаю такой метод практичным

Comment: может так `Paddle(10, 10, 5, 20, 'white')`? А то интерпретатор пытается прочитать переменную `white`, которой у вас нет

Comment: @ThisMan дело в том, что далее переменные попадают в класс с функцией принимающей аргументы в виде `def __init__(self, x, y, sizex, sizey, color):` следом используется метод `self.image.fill(color)` если передавать цвет в строковом формате появляется следующая ошибка _TypeError_ видимо тип переменной должен быть именно кортежем с rgb значениями

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо, попробую найти что-нибудь подходящее

Comment: Попробуйте ``WHITE`` вместо ``white``.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я пробовал более того подключал модуль _colorama_ который в теории должен был решить проблему но на практике не смог. Эта проблема подтолкнула на мысль написать модуль самостоятельно)

Comment: Да, точно. В коде, где я такое подглядел, в самом верху была инициализация WHITE со значениями. Я просто не заметил.

Comment: А почему не записать все нужные цвета в словарь?

Answer (score 0):

В pygam'е есть отдельный словарь для этого, доступный по коду:

```
pygame.color.THECOLORS
```

Так вот, для того, чтобы использовать цвет, вы импортируете этот словарь (желательно так, чтобы не вводить много): `from pygame.color import THECOLORS` , и потом, где вам нужен цвет, пишете `THECOLORS[ <Название цвета в кавычках> ]`